# git push trying to push files not listed in git ls-files

Tags: git, github

I accidentally committed an unnecessary large subfolder xxxxx in my repo, and when I realized this while pushing, I stopped the push midway through.

Then I removed an unnecessary folder xxxxx from the repo using

```
git rm -r --cached xxxxx
```

But while `ls-files` does not show the xxxxx folder, git is still trying to push it when I do `git push`:

```
git push --verbose
(...)

Counting objects: 19, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (18/18), done.
POST git-receive-pack (chunked) 
Writing objects: 100% (19/19), 132.93 MiB | 197.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 19 (delta 5), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: warning: File xxxxx/a.csv is 72.22 MB; this is larger than GitHub Enterprise's recommended maximum file size of 50.00 MB
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected.
remote: error: File xxxxx/b is 112.37 MB; this exceeds GitHub Enterprise's file size limit of 100.00 MB
```

How make git permanently forget about "xxxxx" folder and its contents?

Comment: is the commit with these files the most recent?

Comment: Yes. But this commit also includes some valid changes which I don't want to revert.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`git push` does not push *files*, it pushes *commits*.  Specifically, it pushes commits that you have that they don't (whoever "they" are—the remote to which you are pushing).  They are complaining that at least one of your commits contains at least one large file.

You'll need to push some different commits, so that the commits you're pushing don't contain the large file.

As a general rule, the way to do this is to take each "good" commit intact, copying it to a new branch, and for each "bad" commit, extract the good parts, remove the bad parts, and make a new commit out of the result.  For instance, suppose this is a drawing of the commits the remote has:

```
A <- B <- C <- D    <-- origin/master
```

Suppose you've added three commits but there's a problem in the middle one:

```
A - B - C - D       <-- origin/master
             \
              E - F - G   <-- master
```

When you run `git push` your git sends commits `E`, `F`, and `G`, and the remote complains because `F` has file(s) it should not.  To fix this you can simply copy `E` to a new branch—we'll call the copy `E'`—then copy-but-fix `F` to make `F'`, then copy `G` to make `G'`.  Let's also rename the old ("bad") `master`; in fact, let's just drop the name entirely, so that we have this instead:

```
              E' - F' - G'   <-- master
             /
A - B - C - D       <-- origin/master
             \
              E - F - G      [abandoned]
```

The git command that does this copying is `git rebase`.  Normally it just copies straight through; you want it instead to copy `E`, but then stop and let you fix `F`, and then copy `G`, and the way to get it to do that is to use the `-i` or `--interactive` flag.

In general, you should only copy-while-changing commits that *only you* have, but fortunately this is exactly the set that `git push` should be pushing, and whatever branch you're pushing, `origin/branch` (or whatever the remote name is, if it's not `origin`) will delimit the commits that the remote has (and other people have).

Interactive rebase can do a lot more than this, so see [the Git Book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History) for instructions.  It's also up to you to figure out which of your commit(s) contain which large file(s); for this, `git show` and `git diff` are helpful tools.

Comment: Very interesting, I'm giving my upvote for the educational content itself. Now whether I'm able to solve my mess using this, I'll see in a few hours when I have a chance to try it. If I do, I'll select the answer. Thank you!

Comment: BTW if the "bad" commit is at the tip of the branch, you can use `git commit --amend` directly (as described in the Pro Git book: `git add` and/or `git rm` first, then `git commit --amend`) without the interactive rebase part.  It does the same thing—makes a copy of the original commit, then "abandons" the original in favor of the copy, it's just limited to the one tip-most commit, while rebase can reach back further in the chain.

Comment: Thank you again torek. This helped a great deal, and I learned a lot in the process.

Answer (score 1):

Since the commit, that needs editing is on the head of branch, you probably can get away just with amending it.
So do the `git rm <what you need>` and then `git commit --amend`

This will merge changes into most recent commit, instead of creating new one

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try to put this folder in [gitignore](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) file of git.

Comment: I tried that, doesn't help -- the folder is listed in .gitignore now, and git is still trying to push it to remote.

Comment: Are you sure you specify correctly the files of the folder to be ignored?

Comment: I specify the entire folder as: 

xxxxx/